# React router 4 "NOT FOUND" when I type in the URL in browser

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to learn react router 4 but meet some problems. I follow the guide from here https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/no-match, and yes this example works fine in my browser. I can click the links and get things shown in the browser.

but, if I type in the url in the browser instead of click the links, the page shows NOT FOUND

[NOT FOUND page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2azE.png)

What's happening? Does React-router can only use links instead of typing in URL??

Answer (score 2):

Stijn de Witt explain about this "problem" here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36623117/8272354

When you initialize with the URL in the "inital route" of your route system, all the routes "know" how to deal with Router Links. So, the React Link does't refresh the browser, just change the route internally in javascript and load the specifyc route. This way everything works fine.

But, when you type the route (not the "initial route") directly in the URL, the router system does't understand that route, and the browser will try get this page in the server.