# How to have # urls to save component app state in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

How do we get #urls in React (single-page app)?

1) Visit: https://coinhover.io

2) Click on Portfolio

3) Refresh

### Expected

The Portfolio component re-renders

### Results

The app breaks (I know this is because I'm missing a #)

---

#### App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import Routes from './components/Routes'

const supportsHistory = "pushState" in window.history

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router forceRefresh={!supportsHistory}>
                <Routes />
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(null, null)(App)
```

#### Routes.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { browserHistory, BrowserRouter, hashHistory, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import Portfolio from './portfolio/Portfolio'
import Home from './home/Home'
import NoMatch from './NoMatch'

const Routes = () => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter history={ browserHistory }>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact={ true } path="/" component={ Home }/>
                <Route exact={ true } path="/portfolio" component={ Portfolio }/>
                <Route component={ NoMatch } />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}

export default Routes
```

Comment: How does your server serve the page? It seems like refreshing the browser tries to load `https://coinhover.io/portfolio` from the server and since it doesn't serve anything on that route you get 404.

Comment: I'm not using a server, it's 100% a frontend app

Comment: I know but that page is being served in some way.  How do you do it?

Comment: If you want the `#` in the url you will need to use [HashRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter)

Comment: I agree with @Leon Gaban. A little react router concept is missing to you hehe.

Here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44986464/8272354) I gave some explanation and link to solve your problem (maybe). (I wrote here 'cause I can't comment yet :P).

Comment: Just redirect your 404 to index.html. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually/42094288#42094288)

Comment: @HenriqueOeckslerBertoldi dude that is it! LOL all I needed was HashRouter, do you want to post your answer? I just changed BrowserRouter to HashRouter

Comment: @LeonGaban ur design is good man lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@HenriqueOeckslerBertoldi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8272354/henrique-oecksler-bertoldi)

Using `HashRouter` fixed my problem (see [the docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter))

```
import React from 'react'
import { browserHistory, HashRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import Portfolio from './portfolio/Portfolio'
import Home from './home/Home'
import NoMatch from './NoMatch'

const Routes = () => {
    return (
        <HashRouter history={ browserHistory }>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact={ true } path="/" component={ Home }/>
                <Route exact={ true } path="/portfolio" component={ Portfolio }/>
                <Route component={ NoMatch } />
            </Switch>
        </HashRouter>
    );
}

export default Routes
```